# How to convert a flat list with only integer to a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to convert a list that only contains integers into a nested list. The number of elements in each sub-list within the nested list should be a minimum of one.

**Input**

```py
input_list = [15281, 15285, 15289, 15282, 15286, 15290, 15283, 15287, 15284, 15288, 14590, 14591, 14592]
```

**Expected output**

```py
output_list = [[15281, 15285, 15289], [15282, 15286, 15290], [15283, 15287, 15284], [15288, 14590, 14591], [14592] ]
```

Is there a way to achieve this without converting all integers in the input list to strings before building the nested list?

Comment: Try this : `[input_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(input_list), 3)]`

Comment: Why would the integers need to be converted to strings?

Comment: @sj95126 they were probably going to concatenate everything, take every 15, then change each of those into groups of 5